# For what values of $a$ is $\sqrt[m]{\sqrt[n]a} = \sqrt[mn]a$ true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For what values of $a$ is the following identity true?

$$
\sqrt[m]{\sqrt[n]a} = \sqrt[mn]a
$$

I can prove it for the nonnegative reals. It seems to work for any complex number, but I can't figure out how to prove it.

**Note:** I'm assuming $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers. The question is equivalent to this special case of the identity for exponents: ${{(a^{\frac{1}{n}})}^\frac{1}{m}} = a^{\frac{1}{mn}}$. The identity for exponents where the exponent is any rational been discussed elsewhere on the site. My question is whether this special case of the exponent identity holds for all complex numbers.

Comment: May I see your proof for nonnegative reals? How do you define $\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: For nonnegative real $a$, both sides are nonnegative. You can simply raise both sides of the equation to $mn$ and simplify. I'm not sure what you want as far as the definition of $\sqrt{-1}$. I'm assuming nth root is defined as the principal nth root.

Comment: I'm sorry I misread, I thought you meant that you prove it for negative reals, hence my confusion (and yes I know I wrote nonnegative myself, and then proceeded to take the example of -1, I have no idea why)